# Spark Core - Embed in other application

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a use case to process simple ETL like jobs. The data volume is very 
less (less than few GB), and can fit easily on my running java application's 
memory. I would like to take advantage of Spark dataset api, but don't need 
any spark setup (Standalone / Cluster ). Can I embed spark in existing Java 
application and still use ?

I heard local spark mode is only for testing. For small data sets like, can 
this still be used in production? Please advice if any disadvantages.

Regards 
Reddy

Comment: well, if it's the SQL flavor you're looking for, there are other frameworks like http://josql.sourceforge.net/ that are not designed as distributed frameworks. Not sure if syntax is as strong as spark sql... At any case, if you use local spark in your java application it would work, just as much as you could use Mockito code in production, although it is not designed for such use case

Comment: thank you Lior Chaga, for josql suggestion.  I was specifically looking for Python Pandas like Dataframe support in Java, which Spark provides already. I came across  [morpheus](http://www.zavtech.com/morpheus/api/) library, however, I can't use at my organization unless its from apache community.   I would like to know more reasons about why spark not recommended in embedded mode.